# Location of 1.5.x JDK source code

Tags: java, java-5

I have installed Eclipse 3.3 on Mac OS X and it does not contain the src.zip file I am used to seeing with Windows and Linux installations. Where can I download the complete source code for the Java 1.5 JDK (must be specific versions).

I have been able to locate the full source code, however it contained the ungenerated Buffer implementations and so navigating NIO code was not possible.

**Looking for the Java source typically found in the JDK src.zip, not the VM source.**

Answer (score 4):

You can get the [Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/java/download/), which includes the source. The download requires you to have an ADC account.

Comment: Is there any way to acquire the Java src.zip from elsewhere. Apple only implement the JVM.

Comment: Yes. From Sun. Download a JDK for some other operating system (e.g., Linux).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that was what I was going to have to resort to.

Answer (score 2):

Brian Clapper has already mentioned it in a comment, but the JDK downloads from Sun include src.zip. I don't know if there's any way to get it other than installing on a target platform, but you can install it on a Windows or Linux (virtual) machine and get src.zip from there.

Specifically for Java 1.5, the downloads are [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index_jdk5.jsp)

**[Update]**
Also, source distributions of the JDK are available from Sun from [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/source_license.html). It seems that SCSL link is messed up and throws you for a loop, but JRL still works (if you don't mind going through it).

Comment: Ya, but this does not give the complete code. The ByteBuffer etc are still templates, and other generated code is missing.

Answer (score 1):

It is located in

/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions.1.5.0/Home/src.jar

I do have the XCode stuff installed found on the installation disks that come with a Mac, so I don't know if the source code appears on a standard Mac installation of OSX.

Comment: Well, does not seem to be "find . /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions | grep src" produced nothing. I have approx 8 versions on my machine.

Comment: for 1.6.0_24 it exists /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_24-b07-334.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar. You need the Java Developer Documentation from Apple installed

Answer (score 1):

/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/src.jar

More details on:
http://confluence.concord.org/display/CCTR/Get+local+copies+of+Mac+OS+X+Java+source+code+and+Javadoc

Answer (score 0):

Unclear if that is even possible since the Mac JDK is not, to my knowledge, open source.  It was created by Apple not Sun.

Comment: To clarify, I am looking for the src.zip that contains the Java source for the JDK, rather than the VM source.

Comment: That's what I meant, I don't know that they are the same since the contract is the only thing required to be maintained.