# Source code for the Java library classes

Tags: java

Where can I find the source code for the Java library classes? I mean classes in `rt.jar`.

Platform: Windows.

Comment: when you install the jdk there is an option to also install the sources. after that you will find them in the src.zip just as said below

Comment: where is the source code of tools.jar

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For old versions of Java with separate JRE and JDK downloads, download the JDK.  The sources for the public classes are in src.zip.

Comment: i have jdk1.6. can you tell me the path where it lies.

Comment: It's in `src.zip` in the JDK installation, like he just said.

Comment: i don't have it in the installation folder.

Comment: Then you probably downloaded the JRE, not the JDK.  That's the case if you don't have a /bin directory.

Answer (score 20):

Here's the [browsable source code for OpenJDK 7](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/).

Update: As of June 2018 grepcode seems to be down. Here you can find [an alternative](https://www.zgrepcode.com/java/oracle/).

Update^2: As of October 2020, the two previous links do not work. View it at [OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/) and vote up the [answer by Nosrep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62687925/631051), which I got it from.

Comment: Both links are down as of Oct-2020. See answer by Nosrep. The link mentioned in his answer is working fine. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/

Answer (score 8):

Sources are in `src.zip` located in the installation folder:

- On Windows, the JDK includes `src.zip` [by default](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html) if I remember well.
- On a Linux distro, you may have to install the `sun-java6-source` package.
- On Mac, you'll have to download the Developer Documentation. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440441/location-of-1-5-x-jdk-source-code).

Comment: Could not find SecretKey Interface looking there :-/

Answer (score 6):

As almost all the suggestions seem to be either grepcode or zgrepcode which are both down, I found one from OpenJDK here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/

Edit: a more complete version of all OpenJDK projects and JDK 6-15 can be found here: https://hg.openjdk.java.net/

Edit Edit: Apparently there's a jdk Github repository now, dunno if it was created after this answer or I just couldn't find it; either way: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk

Harder to find classes than in the mercurial repository for me at least, but for example here is the ArrayList file: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java

Or, yknow just use search

Answer (score 5):

If you only need to have a look at the source/implemenation, i would suggest using

[Docjar](http://grepcode.com/)

**Edit**

GrepCode is even better

[GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/)

Comment: This is a wonderful resource for quickly browsing an implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly browse the code online here for Java : https://zgrepcode.com/java/openjdk/10.0.2/

It is a great tool also for browsing most of the open source projects as it gives you internal linking to classes.

Answer (score 1):

As mention above, most of the source files can be found by downloading the SDK.
However for some classes you can find the source code (javax.ssl etc') for I suggest adding the jad eclipse plugin that will decompile any class without using external site such as Docjar.
Jad eclipse info:
http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

There is also grepcode.com (not sure how old this site is, perhaps this answer is an update for new solutions now), sample query:

http://grepcode.com/search?query=java.lang.Math.sin&start=0&entity=type&n=