# How to view native implementations of Java classes?

Tags: java, c++, open-source, native

there are several sites out providing Java source code.
Unluckily, these does not refer to the Java native binaries.
In short: The source code of native functions is not shown.

An example is [StrictMath.floor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/content/Context.java#Context.startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29).
The only thing provided is the raw Java declaration

```
 public static native double floor(double a);
```

What I am interested in is the actual c/c++ code. How did they actually implement it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Source code for the java library classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258031/source-code-for-the-java-library-classes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OpenJDK project contains the full source.  The source for [jdk 6](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/) is roughly equivalent to what is in the Sun/Oracle jdk.  The source for [jdk 7](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/) should be almost exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the native code generated if you use the debug build of the OpenJDK.

StringMath.floor() is turned into a single machine instruction. i.e. some "native" methods are actually inlined by the JVM.  Not sure how that helps you though. ;)

See notes of fistp http://stereopsis.com/FPU.html